# Toggling among tabs using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have tabs section with 3 sections, Each tab has its own heading and content.

But I don't want to show all the 3 tabs, Just what the user select by checking the related checkbox, There are 3 related checkboxes, One for each tab.

Here is the code:

```js
//Function to hide all siblings but leave the clicked one
function hideAllChildrenButOne(parentId, toRevealId) {
 $('#' + parentId).children().css('display', 'none');
 $('#' + toRevealId).css('display', 'block');
}

//Function to show the tab header and content when a checkbox is checked
function showSection(parentId, toRevealId) {
 var relatedSection = $('#' + toRevealId).attr('data-section');
 $('#' + toRevealId).toggleClass('inline-block');
 $('#' + toRevealId).siblings().removeClass('tab_active');
 $('#' + toRevealId).toggleClass('tab_active');
 $('#' + relatedSection).toggleClass('active');
 $('#' + relatedSection).siblings().removeClass('active');
 $('#' + relatedSection).toggleClass('block');
 
 if ($('input[data-header=' + toRevealId + ']').is(':checked')) {
 }else{
 }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

 //On clicking a tab header('Father', 'Mother', 'Brother')
 $('.tab-header').click(function(event) {
  $(this).addClass('tab_active').siblings().removeClass('tab_active');
     var related_section = $(this).attr('data-section');
     hideAllChildrenButOne('relative_content', related_section);
 });

 //On changing any checkbox with name=relative[]
 $("input[name='relative[]']").change(function() {
     var self = $(this);
     console.log(self.value);
     showSection('relative_tabs', self.attr('data-header'));
 });

});
```

```css
.relative_container{
    position: relative;
    padding: 45px 15px 15px;
    margin: 0 -15px 15px;
    border-color: #e5e5e5 #eee #eee;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
 .relative_container {
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-color: #ddd;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     box-shadow: none;
 }
}
.relative_tabs{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 7px 0;
}
.relative_tabs:before{
 display: table;
 content: " ";
} 
.tab-header{
 display: none;
 margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.tab-header>a{
 margin-right: 2px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-header.tab_active>a{
 color: #555;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.relative_content div{
 display: none;
}
.relative_content>div.active{
 display: block;
}
.tab-content{
 display: none;
}
.hidden{
 display: none;
}
.inline-block{
 display: inline-block;
}
.block{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <label>Father<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Father" data-header="father-tab"></label>
 <label>Mother<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Mother" data-header="mother-tab"></label>
 <label>Guardian<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Guardian"></label>
 <label>Other<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Other"></label>
 <div class="relative_container">
  <div class="relative_header">
   <ul class="relative_tabs" id="relative_tabs">
    <li id="father-tab" data-section="Father_info" class="tab-header">
     <a>Father</a>
    </li> 
    <li data-section="Mother_info" class="tab-header" id="mother-tab">
     <a>Mother</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="relative_content" id="relative_content">
   <div class="tab-content" id="Father_info">Father Info</div>
   <div class="tab-content" id="Mother_info">Mother Info</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

There is an issue:

When I check more than 1 checkbox the related tabs are shown but only the last checked one is active, But when I uncheck all of them except one the checked one is not active.

So if the user checked more than one checkbox and checked all except one, This one should become active.

Comment: I think it's because you're using `toggleClass()` rather than explicit `addClass()` and `removeClass()`. If the tab was previously active, this ends up making it inactive.

Comment: @Barmar, This would acquire checking which checkboxes are checked, Right?

Comment: If you have an idea or could edit the JS code that would be great

Comment: What is the desired result when you're unchecking a box? If it was the active tab, which one becomes active in its place? That should work with any number of checked boxes.

Comment: If only 1 remain checked, It should be active, If more then any of the checked should be active, There will be 4 tabs at most

Comment: If you're removing the active tab, just make the first visible tab active. That should work with any number of checked boxes.

Comment: How to check which and how many checkboxes are checked?

Comment: You don't need to know how many checkboxes are checked. that's the point. Just make the tab associated with the first box active. `document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]:checked")` will return the first checked box.

Comment: But in this case how would I know that the user unchecked the active tab?

Comment: `$("#" + relatedSection).hasClass("active")`

Comment: Yes I thought of that too, I tried to count the number of displayed tabs `$("input[name='relative[]']:visible").length`, But this returns the number of elements inside the visible tab

Comment: `$(".tab-content:visible").length`

Comment: You are right, But I used `$(".tab-header:visible")` instead as if the tab is not active, The content would be hidden, Now one last thing, I need to know what checkboxes still checked or tabs still visible to active one of them

Comment: `input:[type=checkbox]:checked`

Comment: Why when I check more than one like father and mother, Then uncheck mother the father tab doesn't become active https://jsfiddle.net/jnba9d0v/4/?

Comment: I tried to apply some css with JS to the first visible tab `$(".tab-header:visible:first")` and it worked, But with `addClass` it's not working, Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think couple of changes in `html` and `javascript` will help you to achieve desired result. In html, I am using almost similar id for tabs and contents (just diff is contents has '_info' suffix).

See the Snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 //On clicking a tab header('Father', 'Mother', 'Brother')
    $('.tab-header').click(function(event) {
      $(this).addClass('tab_active').siblings().removeClass('tab_active');
     $('#relative_content').children().css('display', 'none');
      $('#' + $(this).attr('id')+'_info').css('display', 'block');
    });

    //On changing any checkbox with name=relative[]
    $("input[name='relative[]']").change(function() {
      $('#' + $(this).data('header')).toggleClass('inline-block');
      
      if($(this)[0].checked){
         $('#' + $(this).data('header')).click();
      }else{
       $('#relative_content').children().css('display', 'none');
        if($('.inline-block.tab_active').length == 0 && $('.tab-header.inline-block').length>0){
          $($('.tab-header.inline-block')[0]).click();
        }else{
          $($('.inline-block.tab_active')[0]).click();
        }
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.relative_container{
    position: relative;
    padding: 45px 15px 15px;
    margin: 0 -15px 15px;
    border-color: #e5e5e5 #eee #eee;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
 .relative_container {
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-left: 0;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-color: #ddd;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     box-shadow: none;
 }
}
.relative_tabs{
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 7px 0;
}
.relative_tabs:before{
 display: table;
 content: " ";
} 
.tab-header{
 display: none;
 margin-bottom: -1px;
}
.tab-header>a{
 margin-right: 2px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    padding: 9px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tab-header.tab_active>a{
 color: #555;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.relative_content div{
 display: none;
}
.relative_content>div.active{
 display: block;
}
.tab-content{
 display: none;
}
.hidden{
 display: none;
}
.inline-block{
 display: inline-block;
}
.block{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <label>Father<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Father" data-header="father-tab"></label>
 <label>Mother<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Mother" data-header="mother-tab"></label>
 <label>Guardian<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Guardian" data-header="guardian-tab"></label>
 <label>Other<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="Other" data-header="other-tab"></label>
 <div class="relative_container">
  <div class="relative_header">
   <ul class="relative_tabs" id="relative_tabs">
    <li id="father-tab" data-section="Father_info" class="tab-header">
     <a>Father</a>
    </li> 
    <li data-section="Mother_info" class="tab-header" id="mother-tab">
     <a>Mother</a>
    </li>
    <li data-section="Guardian_info" class="tab-header" id="guardian-tab">
     <a>Guardian</a>
    </li>
    <li data-section="Other_info" class="tab-header" id="other-tab">
     <a>Other</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="relative_content" id="relative_content">
   <div class="tab-content" id="father-tab_info">Father Info</div>
   <div class="tab-content" id="mother-tab_info">Mother Info</div>
   <div class="tab-content" id="guardian-tab_info">Guardian Info</div>
   <div class="tab-content" id="other-tab_info">Other Info</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/pg7yw9fz/) also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simplified example that might help. *For some reason, the StackSnippet is not working, so I also made a jsFiddle of the same to demonstrate.*

Note that I used the class "active" as both a marker (is it on/off?) and to add css. *You can use a different name if you already are using "active" for something else.*

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gabthvrL/1/)

```js
$('[id^=cb]').click(function(){
  var cb = this.id.split('_')[1];
  if ( $('div#d_'+cb).hasClass('active') ){
    $('div#d_'+cb).hide().removeClass('active');
  }else{
    $('div#d_'+cb).show().addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
div{display:inline-block;height:50px;width:50px;margin-right:10px;display:none;}
#d_1{background:yellow;}
#d_2{background:pink;}
#d_3{background:green;}
#d_4{background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cb_1" type="checkbox" />
<input id="cb_2" type="checkbox" />
<input id="cb_3" type="checkbox" />
<input id="cb_4" type="checkbox" />
<section id="wrapper">
  <div id="d_1"></div>
  <div id="d_2"></div>
  <div id="d_3"></div>
  <div id="d_4"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your example is working fine, But in my case there are 2 related elements the tab headings and the content, Not just one element

Comment: + The last checked checkbox tab should become active and leaving the other tabs heading only

Comment: I made some changes trying to implement it, But I need to check how many checkboxes are checked or how many tabs are active

Comment: Took a look - [added an alert](https://jsfiddle.net/jnba9d0v/3/) and seeing unexpected results. Suspect you will need to break down each complex statement and identify where the error is, and then re-compact the code if you still wish to do so. Troubleshooting compacted code is a challenge..! *To see the problem on my jsFiddle revision, do: (a) Mother (b) Mother (c) Mother (d) Father (e) Mother.  The final Mother comes back false, but should be true.  Perhaps you are not querying the element you thought you are - so break down into individual var statements to check each one.*

Comment: That's not what I meant, The tab is shown when only the related checkbox is checked, What I meant is when the user check 2 checkboxes like father and mother, Then he uncheck mother checkbox, In this case father should be the active tab

Comment: So when the user check more than I checkbox and uncheck the last one he checked, One of the other tabs is active

Comment: [Here is an incomplete example](https://jsfiddle.net/jnba9d0v/6/) - would a structure like this be easier to work with/troubleshoot? What would it take to make this new code do what you want? Sorry I cannot do more but I lack the time to fully troubleshoot/solve your original code for you *but hopefully this refactoring will help.* **Also Note** that I added the line ***debugger;*** into the jsFiddle. When Chrome's DevTools is open (F12), the code will break at that point and you can use F10 and F11 to step-through the code. Did you already know about that? It's useful!